# Cant start a dialog activity from a button in another activity

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to start a new activity as a Dialog Activity putting a Intent on a button from another activity. Whenever I try and press the button, the activity unfotunately closes.

Main Activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button ab = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        ab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewDialog.class);
                startActivity(intent);



    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void side(View view){
         android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm1 = getSupportFragmentManager();
         NewDialog newdialog = new NewDialog();
         newdialog.show(fm1, "SideDialog");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
}
```

NewDialog.java

```
public class NewDialog extends DialogFragment{

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState){
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_new_dialog, container);
        getDialog().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);


                return view;

    }
}
```

Added Logcat:

```
05-29 22:37:36.472: D/dalvikvm(26806): Late-enabling CheckJNI
05-29 22:37:36.762: D/ActivityThread(26806): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
05-29 22:37:36.762: D/ActivityThread(26806): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
05-29 22:37:36.762: D/ActivityThread(26806): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
05-29 22:37:39.172: D/libEGL(26806): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
05-29 22:37:39.222: D/libEGL(26806): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
05-29 22:37:39.322: D/libEGL(26806): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
05-29 22:37:39.362: I/Adreno200-EGL(26806): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:299>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3.1_RB1.04.01.01.45.000_msm8625_JB_REL_2.0.3.1_Merge_release_AU (Merge)
05-29 22:37:39.362: I/Adreno200-EGL(26806): Build Date: 03/28/13 Thu
05-29 22:37:39.362: I/Adreno200-EGL(26806): Local Branch: 
05-29 22:37:39.362: I/Adreno200-EGL(26806): Remote Branch: m/jb_rel_2.0.3.1
05-29 22:37:39.362: I/Adreno200-EGL(26806): Local Patches: NONE
05-29 22:37:39.362: I/Adreno200-EGL(26806): Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
05-29 22:37:39.452: D/OpenGLRenderer(26806): Enabling debug mode 0
05-29 22:37:43.822: D/AndroidRuntime(26806): Shutting down VM
05-29 22:37:43.822: W/dalvikvm(26806): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40fd4438)
05-29 22:37:44.022: E/AndroidRuntime(26806): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-29 22:37:44.022: E/AndroidRuntime(26806): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.createdialog/com.example.createdialog.NewDialog}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.createdialog.NewDialog cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
05-29 22:37:44.022: E/AndroidRuntime(26806):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2038)
05-29 22:37:44.022: E/AndroidRuntime(26806):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
05-29 22:37:44.022: E/AndroidRuntime(26806):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
05-29 22:37:44.022: E/AndroidRuntime(26806):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
05-29 22:37:44.022: E/AndroidRuntime(26806):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-29 22:37:44.022: E/AndroidRuntime(26806):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-29 22:37:44.022: E/AndroidRuntime(26806):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4963)
05-29 22:37:44.022: E/AndroidRuntime(26806):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-29 22:37:44.022: E/AndroidRuntime(26806):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-29 22:37:44.022: E/AndroidRuntime(26806):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
05-29 22:37:44.022: E/AndroidRuntime(26806):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
05-29 22:37:44.022: E/AndroidRuntime(26806):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-29 22:37:44.022: E/AndroidRuntime(26806): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.createdialog.NewDialog cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
05-29 22:37:44.022: E/AndroidRuntime(26806):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
05-29 22:37:44.022: E/AndroidRuntime(26806):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2029)
05-29 22:37:44.022: E/AndroidRuntime(26806):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: We will need to see the logcat output to help. However, I would guess that it is a NullPointerException relating to your Button. You should declare the button at the class level with `private Button ab;` and then assign it in your onCreate() with `ab = (Button) findViewById(...)`

Comment: Have u declared `NewDialog` in Mainfest.xml

Comment: Yes I declared it in Manifest.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be wrong here, but as far as I know, you can't start an `Intent` passing a `DialogFragment`, you should pass an `Activity`. Here's what's wrong:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewDialog.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Since `NewDialog` is declared as a `DialogFragment` and not as an `Activity` subclass.

If what you are trying to do is **show** the dialog, then you should do:

```
NewDialog dialog = NewDialog();

// use getSupportFragmentManager() if using support fragments instead of native fragments, or
// use getChildFragmentManager() if this code is inside a fragment rather than an activity
dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "pass-any-string-here");
```

Comment: How should I stsrt the Dialog as I press the button?

Comment: Will it work if the activities(Main and NewDialog) are in different packages? Because it is asking me to create the show method in the dialog activity.

Comment: Yes it will. But you should notice that, in your definition, `NewDialog` is **not** an `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

Without a logcat stacktrace to look at, I am assuming that your issue has to do with variable scope ([here is an example explanation on the topic](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html)).

What you need to do is declare your button as a class level variable because right now it is a method variable and as such ceases to exist once your onCreate method has finished executing.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private Button myButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(...);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Now that you've added the logcat we can see that the issue lies with attempting to use the Dialog as an Activity. In future questions please always include a logcat/stacktrace if there is one. Otherwise people will just be somewhat guessing where the error is.